# Django static files not working in azure

Tags: django, visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, django-staticfiles

I have a django project on the azure right now and I can't load the statics files. When I run my program on Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), I only get the HTML on the browser (no css or other static files). I run the same code on visual studio on my computer and everything looks fine but when I put it on azure something goes wrong. Any help??

Comment: Did you use VSO for continuous deployment from your repository to Azure Web App, right?

Comment: Please inspect the absolute urls for the relative path of css or other static files, and make sure whether the urls are available for accessing and change the path with comparing the difference for the path between on VSO and at local . If you have published the app on Azure, you can inspect these static files via Kudu Console.

Comment: I just put all my static files inside the static folder in each app. I did not mess with the directories now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put all my static files inside the static folder in each app. I did not mess with the directories and how the folders are organized. So static_dirs are static folders in each app folder and the static root is the static folder is the project folder. I am pretty sure there is something wrong with my setting.py that I could not change the static_dir directory so I just decided to use the default directories. Now it works.